# PySimpleGui throwing error when i try to login my bot

Tags: tkinter, bots, pysimplegui

I am writing a bot manager for an app and I keep getting this error, I am not using the threading lib nor a Worker thread:

```
    log_msg = self.ui_element.get()
  File "C:\Users\derri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 3515, in get
    value = str(self.TKText.get(1.0, tk.END))
  File "C:\Users\derri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3706, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', index1, index2)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`
```

The function:

```py
    def emit(self, record):
        # Get the current logs
        log_msg = self.ui_element.get()

        # Format the log record and append
        log_msg += self.format(record)
        print(record)

        # Update the UI element with the log message
        self.ui_element.update(log_msg)

ui_handler = UiLogHandler(window["logs"])
logging.getLogger().addHandler(ui_handler)
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.  Are you using threads?

Comment: Have you tried searching for that error message on this site? There are over 20 separate questions about this error.

Comment: @Alexander I am not using threads nor worker threads

Comment: @BryanOakley I have looked but this seems to be unique to me in the sense I am not using more than one thread

Comment: _Something_ must be using more than one thread. It's impossible to get that error if you're only using the main thread. Please provide a complete (but _minimal_!) [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `emit` called not in the main loop or main thread, so don't update GUI element in this method, replace it by method `Window.write_event_value` to generate an event to update your GUI element in your event loop, like

```py
    def emit(self, record):
        # Get the current logs
        log_msg = self.ui_element.get()

        # Format the log record and append
        log_msg += self.format(record)
        print(record)

        # Update the UI element with the log message
        self.window.write_event_value('Update', log_msg)
```

and in your event loop

```py
    if event == 'Update':
        log_msg = values[event]
        ui_element.update(log_msg)
```